# No keyword with name '=' found in robot

Tags: json, keyword, robotframework

I'm writing a test case in robot framework. I'm getting the response in below json string:

```
{"responseTimeStamp":"1970-01-01T05:30:00",
 "statusCode":"200",
 "statusMsg":"200",
 "_object":{"id":"TS82",
            "name":"newgroup",
            "desc":"ttesteste",
            "parentGroups":[],
            "childGroups":[],
            "devices":null,
            "mos":null,
            "groupConfigRules" {
                "version":null,
                "ruleContents":null
            },
            "applications":null,"type":0
           }
}
```

From that I want to take "_object" using:

```
${reqresstr}        =       ${response['_object']}
```

... but am getting the error "No keyword with name '=' found" error

If I try the following:

```
${reqresstr}=       ${response['_object']}
```

... I'm getting the error "Keyword name cannot be empty." I tried removing the '=' but still get the same error.

How can I extract '_object' from that json string?

Answer (score 3):

When using the "=" for variable assignment with the space-separated format, you must make sure you have no more than a single space before the "=". Your first example shows that you've got more than one space on either side of the "=". You must have only a single space before the `=` and two or more after, or robot will think the spaces are a separator between a keyword and argument.

For the "keyword must not be empty" error, the first cell after a variable name must be a keyword. Unlike traditional programming languages, you cannot directly assign a string to a variable.

To set a variable to a string you need to use the [Set Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable) keyword (or one of the variations such as [Set Test Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable)). For example:

```
${reqresstr}=      Set variable  ${response['_object']}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a syntax error in your command. Make sure there is a space between `${reqresstr}` and `=`.

Using your example above:

```
${reqresstr} =   ${response['_object']}
```

Comment: this answer isn't quite correct. The problem isn't the lack of a space, the problem is that there are too many spaces before the `=`. There can be zero or one, but not two or more.

Answer (score -1):

`${reqresstr}=  '${response["_object"]}'`

wrap it inside quotes and two spaces after `=`